# Read from a file into a vector in matlab using importdata()

Tags: matlab, file, import

My input file looks like this:

```
    # FILE:app/src/f1.c
    2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 24 32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  
    # FILE:src/f2.c
    1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 24 31 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
    ...............
```

I want to read the headers i.e., the lines which start with #, and the vectors present below the headers into lists. I tried the using importdata() as below. But this gives me only the first header and first vector. I need to read it till the end of the file.

```
filename = 'output.txt';
A = importdata(filename);
disp(A.rowheaders);
disp(A.data);
```

EDIT: A = importdata(filename,'#'); This solved my problem

Comment: Don't add the solution in the question. Put that as an answer instead. Btw that solution doesn't import the data in the form of a struct which apparently you were trying to do. It imports the data as a cell instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [fgetl](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) command should do the trick.

I would put it in a for loop with two `fgetl` commands, one for the metadata line and one for the numerical data line.

EDIT: Added example

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');

celHeaders = {};
celData = {};
while(~feof(fid))
    celHeaders{end+1} = fgetl(fid);
    celData{end+1} = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);

disp(celHeaders)
disp(celData)
```

This is assuming that your text file doesn't include additional lines above or below the data.